# Not writing files while running python script from XCode

Tags: python, xcode, cocoa, imagemagick

I'm trying to execute a python script from a cocoa app I created using XCode. The issue is that, the files are not getting written to the desired location. When I run the script through the terminal, its working fine. I tried running it as root as well. Still not working

Here's the error that's coming up:

```
convert: unable to open image ` /Users/anil/Desktop/mp_checkmarkgreen_md_d_lt.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
convert: WriteBlob Failed ` /Users/anil/Desktop/mp_checkmarkgreen_md_d_lt.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1805.
```

Is there anything else I should be doing while running the script?

Comment: The error is 'No such file or directory', is that an extra leading space I see before the first / ?

Comment: That was the issue. I wasn't passing the arguments properly. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I feel so stupid!

Comment: No not stupid, anyone can make that mistake.  It is a good illustration of making sure you read the error message.  Give yourself a break!

Comment: @cdarke Please answer the question so that I won't return to this question again thinkin that it is unanswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is 'No such file or directory', is that an extra leading space I see before the first / ?
:-)